# How do I specify nexus credentials with `gradle init`?

Tags: gradle

When running `gradle init` to facilitate migration from a maven pom to a gradle build, is there a way to specify credentials for a repository that requires them for read-only access (our local nexus repo requires auth even for reads)?

Usually it fails because our parent pom would require read-only authentication to pull down from the local repo, but it doesn't seem like you can specify these credentials until after the build.gradle file already exists, which is counter-intuitive to the `gradle init` purpose.

Adding them via `~/.gradle/.gradle.properties` or through various  `~/.gradle/init.gradle` methods doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

What does your `~/.gradle/init.gradle` look like? Something like this should work:

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
      url 'https://your.nexus/server'
      credentials {
        username "your_username"
        password "your_password"
      }
    }
  }
}
```